# How to 'setstate' an element from one AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I made two forms with pass fields on both, then made all the code to, when the user clicks in the eye Icon, the field show the password, clicking again it hide the password.
But now I put these forms inside an Alert Dialog widget and now it doesn't updating when I click in the icon, only updates if I close the dialog and open again (you open the dialog, click in the icon, it doesn't change. If you close and open again you see the icon changed)

After some search I tried Stateful Builder but it doesn't work too.

Dialog:

```dart
Future<void> _myDialog(child){
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: AlertDialog(
              content: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
              ),
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

Toggle method referenced in my textFields:

```dart
void _toggle(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toggleList[index] = !_toggleList[index];
    });
  }
```

How can I toggle it instantly when the user click in the icon as outside the alert?

**Edit**

```dart
Row _showButtons(){
    return Row(
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Change email"),

            onPressed: () {_myDialog(_showEmailFields());}
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Change pass"),

            onPressed: () {_myDialog(_showPassFields());}
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you add the code of your child as well?

Comment: the problem is setState method you are using in your toggle method is not the one comming from alert dialog

Comment: A better implementation is to make a separate statefulWidget for your child. and don't use StatefulBuilder in AlertDialog.

Comment: Can you show it?

Comment: can you add the code of your complete route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a structure for you that you should use for achieving what you want here. Make your forms into a separate stateful widgets, so that they have their own State, and you call the right setState function. Right now the setState function you are calling does not belongs to the state of your alert dialog.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  void showForm() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Login"),
          content: LoginWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Appbar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Show Form"),
          onPressed: showForm,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  LoginWidgetState createState() => LoginWidgetState();
}

class LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;
  bool _passwordVisible;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    _passwordVisible = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(
                    _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```